# TortioseGit & Submodule

Tags: git-submodules, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit for version control of my project. Within my project I use some submodules. I did change to submodule's files and locally commit the changes for submodule. Now I would like to push it all my project repo and submodule repo. By clicking on context Menu of TotioseGit Menu -> Push I am able to push my repo but not submodules changes. I need to do it from within submodule .git.

Is there context menu or option which give a capability to push it all repo including submodule? Or check it that submodules has been locally modified and changes are not push/sync with remote submodule?

Thank you.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this question and realized that TortoiseGit now offers such an option in its push dialog.

In the TortoiseGit push dialog of your main module simply select the desired submodule option.

[image: TortoiseGit supports submodules in its push dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your git version?

```
Versions 1.7.0 and later of git contain an change in the behavior of git submodule.  
Submodules are now regarded as dirty if they have any modified files or untracked files.
```

So what you are asking for is already there, unless you disabled it with :

```
--ignore-submodules
```

Git option

Comment: I use TortoiseGit 1.8.11.0 and git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1

Comment: You mean I disabled submodules within TortoiseGit somehow? So how can I enable it? I do not have it within .gitigonre "--ignore-submodules"

Comment: Can you paste in your question the output of `git config --list` ?

Answer (score 0):

By applying

```
>>git config --list
```

I got

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
diff.tool=winmerge
difftool.bc3.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4\BComp.exe
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.bc3.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4\BComp.exe
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession -noPlugin
color.ui=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=http://pepe@sw-stash.emspin.net/scm/mcroz/mc010_acim_framework.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.HVP.remote=origin
branch.HVP.merge=refs/heads/KV31_HVP
submodule.freemaster/MCAT/src.url=http://sw-stash.emspin.net/scm/mcroz/mc002_mcat_tool.git
submodule.src/Motor Structure.url=http://sw-stash.emspin.net/scm/mcroz/mc008_mc_algos.git
submodule.src/SAC.url=http://sw-stash.emspin.net/scm/mcroz/mc007_sac_drv.git
credential.helper=!'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\GitCredStore\git-credential-winstore.exe'
```